# Numpy advanced indexing using a 2D array of row indices without broadcasting the output

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an ndarray `array` with ndim 3, and some indices ndarray `idxs` with ndim 2, which specify indices for the first dimension of `array`. The first dimension of `idxs` matches the second dimension of `array`, i.e. `idxs.shape[0] == array.shape[1]`.

I want to get a resulting ndarray `result` with ndim 3 and shape `(idxs.shape[1], array.shape[1], array.shape[2])` like this:

```
for i0 in range(idxs.shape[1]):
    for i1 in range(array.shape[1]):
        result[i0, i1] = array[idxs[i1, i0], i1]
```

How can I get this more directly?

I thought about using advanced indexing but I'm not exactly sure how that would look like.

In Theano, the following works:

```
dim1 = theano.tensor.arange(array.shape[1])
result = array[idxs[dim1], dim1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `for` loop does this:

```
out[i, j] == array[idxs[j, i], j]
```

That is to say, the j,i<sup>th</sup> element in `idxs` gives the *row* index into `array` for the i,j<sup>th</sup> element in `out`. The corresponding set of *column* indices into `array` are just the sequence integers between 0 and `idxs.shape[0] - 1` (which happens to be the same as `array.shape[1] - 1` in this case, but need not be in general).

Your `for` loop can therefore be replaced with a single array indexing operation like this:

```
def simplified(array, idxs):
    return array[idxs.T, np.arange(idxs.shape[0])]
```

We can test for correctness and speed against the functions in @Divakar's answer:

```
m, n = 500, 400
array = np.random.rand(m, n)
idxs = np.random.randint(n, size=(n, m))

print(np.allclose(forloop(array, idxs), simplified(array, idxs)))
# True

%timeit forloop(array, idxs)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 101 ms per loop

%timeit broadcasted_indexing(array, idxs)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 4.1 ms per loop

%timeit simplified(array, idxs)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.66 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the simplified version. I don't exactly understand why this isn't the same as just `array[idxs.T]`. It will always try to match multiple index vectors, but not doing so when the index for a dimension is implicit?

Comment: This sort of thing often trips me up too. It's much easier to understand the 1D case. `idxs.T` is interpreted as a 2D array of row indices, so if `array` was an `(m,)` 1D array then `array[idxs.T]` would have shape `(m, n)` (since you're sampling multiple times from each row). In your case `array` is already `(m, n)`, so the result of `array[idxs.T]` is `(m, n, n)` because numpy keeps the 'existing' column dimension. To collapse the 'existing' column dimension you need to give it another 1D vector of indices.

Answer (score 3):

Create a 2D grid of indices corresponding to row indexing : `idxs[i1, i0]` and use a `N x 1` array for column indexing. When indexed into `array` like that, the column indices would be `broadcasted` to the shape of the row indices. Thus, we would have a [`broadcasted indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays) based approach, like so -

```
# Get 2D grid of row indices corresponding to two nested loops
row_idx = idxs[np.arange(array.shape[1])[:,None],np.arange(idxs.shape[1])]

# Use column indices alongwith row_idx to index into array. 
# The column indices would be broadcasted when put as Nx1 array.
result = array[row_idx,np.arange(array.shape[1])[:,None]].T
```

Please note that as mentioned in the comments by @ali_m, [`np.ix_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) could also be used to create `row_idx`, like so -

```
row_idx = idxs[np.ix_(np.arange(array.shape[1]),np.arange(idxs.shape[1]))]
```

**Runtime tests and verify output**

Function definitions :

```
def broadcasted_indexing(array,idxs):
    row_idx = idxs[np.arange(array.shape[1])[:,None],np.arange(idxs.shape[1])]
    return array[row_idx,np.arange(array.shape[1])[:,None]].T

def forloop(array,idxs):
    result = np.zeros((idxs.shape[1],array.shape[1]))
    for i0 in range(idxs.shape[1]):
        for i1 in range(array.shape[1]):
            result[i0, i1] = array[idxs[i1, i0], i1]
    return result
```

Runtime tests and verify output :

```
In [149]: # Inputs
     ...: m = 500
     ...: n = 400
     ...: array = np.random.rand(m,n)
     ...: idxs = np.random.randint(0,array.shape[1],(n,m))
     ...: 

In [150]: np.allclose(broadcasted_indexing(array,idxs),forloop(array,idxs))
Out[150]: True

In [151]: %timeit forloop(array,idxs)
10 loops, best of 3: 136 ms per loop

In [152]: %timeit broadcasted_indexing(array,idxs)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.01 ms per loop
```

Comment: There's a convenience function [`np.ix_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) designed for this very purpose

Comment: @ali_m Thanks! I keep forgetting about that one, just added that one. So, that could replace how `row_idx` could be created, but seems like `np.ix_` won't work with 2D array inputs, so the final step would still need "broadcasted indexing", right? I am not even sure what to call it :)

Comment: Actually `row_idx` is exactly the same as `idxs`, so you could just do `array[idxs, np.arange(array.shape[1])[:, None]].T` (or `array[idxs.T, np.r_[:array.shape[1]]]` for compactness).

Comment: @ali_m Ah yes! Initially I wasn't assuming `idxs.shape[0] == array.shape[1]`, but with it, it seems `idxs` would be same as `row_idx`. That `np.r_` is another great tool, thanks a lot! Consider posting all that as an answer!